Google sheets unique a list WITHOUT blank cells AND specific texts
I'm trying to list all my unique cells WITHOUT the blank cells and without 2 texts that appear in the list.
I have provided 2 screenshots.
Right now I have split it into;
Filtering the blank space out with;
=UNIQUE(filter(raw!B:B,raw!B:B<>""))

Filtering the specific words I want out with;
=UNIQUE(filter(raw!B:B,NOT(REGEXMATCH(raw!B:B, "Total|Product_display_name"))))

But I want to do both in one formula but just can't figure out how?
Without words

Without text



You may go with:
=UNIQUE(filter(raw!B:B, raw!B:B<>"", NOT(REGEXMATCH(raw!B:B, "Total|Product_display_name"))))

OR
=UNIQUE(filter(raw!B:B,NOT(REGEXMATCH(raw!B:B, "Total|Product_display_name|^$"))))

